# Differentiate $y= x(4-9x^4)^4$

Tags: calculus

So the textbook tells me to do the following question but I can't seem to get the right answer. (answer: $(4-9x^4)^3(4-45x^4)$

This is what I've done:

*apply the product rule*

$u = x$

$u' = 1$

$v = (4-9x^4)^4$

$v' = -144x^3 (4-9x^4)^3$

I used the product rule and got: $(4-9x^4)^3 (-153x^4+ 4)$

What am I doing wrong?

edit: the textbook has the wrong answer, thanks anyways :D

Comment: One thing you're probably doing wrong is not correctly informing us what the question is.  Currently it says "Differentiate $y = x(-9x^4)4$.  I don't think that can be right. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The product rule is $(uv)' = u'v+uv'$, why would you multiply $uv'$ by $v'u$?

Comment: It seems that he wants to diffrentiate $x(4-9x^4)^4$.

Comment: sorry it was a typo.

Comment: $u$ should be $x^3$ according to your problem..

Comment: everyone has been editing it so it's not meant to be x^3, anyways i think the textbook has the wrong answer :)

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook is wrong. I checked your answer myself and also let Wolfram Alpha do the same. Your answer is right.

Also we do not multiply $uv'$ with $vu'$ in product rule. We add them though I noticed you did not make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$y = x\left(4-9x^4\right)^4$

Use the product rule, $\left(uv\right)' = u'v + uv'$, setting:

$u = x$, $v = \left(4-9x^4\right)^4$.

Then,

$u' = 1$

Using the chain rule on $v$, we get:

$v' = 4\left(4-9x^4\right)^3 \cdot \left(-36x^3\right) = -144x^3\left(4-9x^4\right)^3$

Now, $\left(uv\right)' = u'v + uv' = \left(4-9x^4\right)^4 + -144x^4\left(4-9x^4\right)^3 = \left(4-9x^4\right)^3\left(4-9x^4-144x^4\right)$.

The answer is therefore $\left(4-9x^4\right)^3\left(4-153x^4\right)$, so you were correct, assuming the problem was transcribed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$y=x(4-9x^4)^4$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}y=\frac{d}{dx}(x(4-9x^4)^4)$$
 applying product rule we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=4x(4-9x^4)^3(-9\cdot 4x^3)+(4-9x^4)^4(1)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(4-9x^4)^3(-144x^4+4-9x^4)$$ $$ =(4-153x^4)(4-9x^4)^3$$